# Can't call java constructor in spock test

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I'm trying to call java constructor from class which extends GebSpec in Spock test.
I have this error:"Constructors are not allowed; instead, define a 'setup()' or 'setupSpec()' method".
I need call something like that:

```
public class Slider extends GebSpec{
private elem
public Slider(selector) {
    this.elem = page.driver.findElement(By.id(selector))
}

class Mytest extends GebSpec {
    def "try_to_call"() {
        given:
        to SomePage;
        when:
        Slider slider = new Slider("slider");
        then:
         ....some code....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to call test from another test. It's a bad idea))

Answer (score 1):

`Slider` should not extend `GebSpec` because then you would instantiate and call a test from a test. Let Spock or JUnit do the job to run tests, okay?

Answer (score 0):

Spock documentation for [`Mocking Constructor`](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#MockingConstructors) itself reads -

> (Think twice before using this feature. It might be better to change
>   the design of the code under specification.)
>
> Global mocks support mocking of constructors:

For your use case could probably be like -

```
def someSlider = GroovySpy(Slider, global: true)

1 * new Slider("slider")
```